# Как вернуть динамический массив из функции в Go

Tags: golang

Здраствуйте, начал изучать Go и решил реализовать функцию, которая возвращает sha256 или sha512 для входных данных в зависимости от флага, но столкнулся с проблемой возврата разных типов. Вот код:

```
    func sha256or512(s string) []byte {
      if *sha { return sha512.Sum512([]byte(s)) }
      return sha256.Sum256([]byte(s))
    }
```

При компиляции выводит ошибку:

```
/main.go:20:33: cannot use sha512.Sum512(([]byte)(s)) (type [64]byte) as type []byte in return argument
./main.go:21:23: cannot use sha256.Sum256(([]byte)(s)) (type [32]byte) as type []byte in return argument
```

Подскажите как решить данную проблему.

Comment: Только имейте ввиду что это не динамический массив, а срез. Динамических массивов в Go нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Где то так

```
func sha256or512(s string) []byte {
  if *sha {
    r := sha512.Sum512([]byte(s))
    return r[:]
  }
  z := sha256.Sum256([]byte(s))
  return z[:]
}
```

а прям так `sha256.Sum256([]byte(s))[:]` написать нельзя :(

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь)